# find p values from the correlation co-efficient

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary which contains correlation values ,

```
{u'1306': -0.20028268502286309, u'678': nan, u'575': -0.41858161444186959,   u'889': nan, u'984': -1.0, u'258': nan, u'1203': -0.34074604870778746, u'1000': -0.39718585102729265}
```

How can I find p values for the above results, I used the below code to get the value

```
def calculate_pvalue(self,data,size):
    self.data=data
    self.size=size
    self.pvalue=self.data*math.sqrt((self.size-2)/(1-pow(self.data,2)))
    return(self.pvalue)
```

I get the result as follows,

```
{u'1306': -109.51766328031098, u'678': nan, u'1203': -194.16993218970686, u'889': nan, u'984': -inf, u'258': nan, u'575': -246.9217742472556, u'1000': -231.85995387407439}
```

But my question is p values have to be in probability? How can I get my p values for the above correlation, are my steps correct to find the correlation?

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the value of *t* as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution

You should then look up the *p* value from Student's *t*-distribution.

See [How to calculate the statistics “t-test” with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2324438/222914).

Comment: I dint get what you said sir, ok ignoring my code here how do we find the p values from the given correlation result