# How to perform two-sample one-tailed t-test with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In `R`, it is possible to perform two-sample one-tailed t-test simply by using

```
> A = c(0.19826790, 1.36836629, 1.37950911, 1.46951540, 1.48197798, 0.07532846)
> B = c(0.6383447, 0.5271385, 1.7721380, 1.7817880)
> t.test(A, B, alternative="greater")

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  A and B 
t = -0.4189, df = 6.409, p-value = 0.6555
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.029916       Inf 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.9954942 1.1798523
```

In Python world, `scipy` provides similar function [ttest_ind](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy.stats.ttest_ind), but which can only do two-tailed t-tests. Closest information on the topic I found is [this](http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/scipy-stats-one-sided-two-sided-less-greater-signed-td3730.html#a31795926) link, but it seems to be rather a discussion of the policy of implementing one-tailed vs two-tailed in `scipy`.

Therefore, my question is that does anyone know any examples or instructions on how to perform one-tailed version of the test using `numpy/scipy`?

Comment: As of scipy version `1.6.0` performing a one-sided ttest is now a parameter in [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy-stats-ttest-ind). you can now mess with the `alternative` parameter.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From your mailing list link:

> because the one-sided tests can  be backed out from the two-sided
>   tests. (With symmetric distributions  one-sided p-value is just half
>   of the two-sided pvalue)

It goes on to say that scipy always gives the test statistic as signed. This means that given p and t values from a two-tailed test, you would reject the null hypothesis of a greater-than test when `p/2 < alpha and t > 0`, and of a less-than test when `p/2 < alpha and t < 0`.

Comment: I am a bit confused by this formulation of `t`. H0: first is greater than second
`first = np.random.normal(3,2,400);
 second = np.random.normal(6,2,400);
t, p = stats.ttest_ind(first, second, axis=0, equal_var=True)
t-stat = -23.0,  p-value/2 = 1.33e-90
`
So, I have a null hypothesis of greater-than test but t<0, meaning I cannot reject the null-hypothesis?

Comment: @Tonja: you are getting a negative t-stat because the difference between the first mean and the second mean is negative.

The difference of means that `scipy.stats.ttest_ind(a, b)` computes is `mean(a)-mean(b)`, so if your Alternative Hypothesis that you are trying to prove is that `mean(second)>mean(first)`, then you can call `scipy.stats.ttest_ind(second, first)` and you don't have to worry about signs. In this case reject the Null Hypothesis (i.e. `mean(second)<=mean(first)`) if `p-value/2 < alpha`, which is equivalent to `t>t_crit(df)`,

Comment: ... `t_crit(df)` is the critical t-value for `df` degrees of freedom which is basically `sample_size_1 + sample_size_2 -2` and can be read off a statistical table like this one http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/tables.

Comment: ... for a one-tailed test (or this one http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/t-table.pdf for a two-tailed test).

Answer (score 33):

After trying to add some insights as comments to the accepted answer but not being able to properly write them down due to general restrictions upon comments, I decided to put my two cents in as a full answer.

First let's formulate our investigative question properly. The data we are investigating is

```
A = np.array([0.19826790, 1.36836629, 1.37950911, 1.46951540, 1.48197798, 0.07532846])
B = np.array([0.6383447, 0.5271385, 1.7721380, 1.7817880])
```

with the sample means

```
A.mean() = 0.99549419
B.mean() = 1.1798523
```

I assume that since the mean of B is obviously greater than the mean of A, you would like to check if this result is statistically significant.

So we have the Null Hypothesis

```
H0: A >= B
```

that we would like to reject in favor of the Alternative Hypothesis

```
H1: B > A
```

Now when you call `scipy.stats.ttest_ind(x, y)`, this makes a Hypothesis Test on the value of `x.mean()-y.mean()`,  which means that in order to get positive values throughout the calculation (which simplifies all considerations) we have to call

```
stats.ttest_ind(B,A)
```

instead of `stats.ttest_ind(B,A)`. We get as an answer

- `t-value = 0.42210654140239207`
- `p-value = 0.68406235191764142`

and since according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) this is the output for a two-tailed t-test we must divide the `p` by 2 for our one-tailed test. So depending on the Significance Level `alpha` you have chosen you need

```
p/2 < alpha
```

in order to reject the Null Hypothesis `H0`. For `alpha=0.05` this is clearly not the case so **you cannot reject** `H0`.

An alternative way to decide if you reject `H0` without having to do any algebra on `t` or `p` is by looking at the t-value and comparing it with the critical t-value `t_crit` at the desired level of confidence (e.g. 95%) for the number of degrees of freedom `df` that applies to your problem. Since we have

```
df = sample_size_1 + sample_size_2 - 2 = 8
```

we get from a statistical table like [this one](http://www.statisticshowto.com/tables/t-distribution-table/) that

```
t_crit(df=8, confidence_level=95%) = 1.860
```

We clearly have

```
t < t_crit
```

so we obtain again the same result, namely that **we cannot reject** `H0`.

Comment: Let's say I want only the p-values for each one tailed test: stats.ttest_ind(B,A) and stats.ttest_ind(A,B). How should I think? Take 1-p/2 if the t-stat is < 0?

Answer (score 7):

```
    from scipy.stats import ttest_ind  
    
    def t_test(x,y,alternative='both-sided'):
            _, double_p = ttest_ind(x,y,equal_var = False)
            if alternative == 'both-sided':
                pval = double_p
            elif alternative == 'greater':
                if np.mean(x) > np.mean(y):
                    pval = double_p/2.
                else:
                    pval = 1.0 - double_p/2.
            elif alternative == 'less':
                if np.mean(x) < np.mean(y):
                    pval = double_p/2.
                else:
                    pval = 1.0 - double_p/2.
            return pval

    A = [0.19826790, 1.36836629, 1.37950911, 1.46951540, 1.48197798, 0.07532846]
    B = [0.6383447, 0.5271385, 1.7721380, 1.7817880]

    print(t_test(A,B,alternative='greater'))
    0.6555098817758839
```

Answer (score 4):

When null hypothesis is `Ho: P1>=P2` and alternative hypothesis is `Ha: P1<P2`. In order to test it in Python, you write `ttest_ind(P2,P1)`. (Notice the position is P2 first).

```
first = np.random.normal(3,2,400)
second = np.random.normal(6,2,400)
stats.ttest_ind(first, second, axis=0, equal_var=True)
```

You will get the result like below
`Ttest_indResult(statistic=-20.442436213923845,pvalue=5.0999336686332285e-75)`

In Python, when `statstic <0` your real p-value is actually `real_pvalue = 1-output_pvalue/2= 1-5.0999336686332285e-75/2`, which is approximately 0.99. As your p-value is larger than 0.05, you cannot reject the null hypothesis that 6>=3. when `statstic >0`, the real z score is actually equal to `-statstic`, the real p-value is equal to pvalue/2.

Ivc's answer should be when `(1-p/2) < alpha and t < 0`, you can reject the less than hypothesis.

Comment: It's quite surprised me when I was reading your post. From my opinion, I think that in 1 sided p-value, p should always is out_p/2. Can you give me some related docs about (1-p/2)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html), only if the parameter `equal_var` is set to **False**, can `stats.ttest_ind()` perform the one-tailed hypothesis test. Hence, your example shows a two-tailed hypothesis test, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this function from R: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test

```
def ttest(a, b, axis=0, equal_var=True, nan_policy='propagate',
          alternative='two.sided'):        
    tval, pval = ttest_ind(a=a, b=b, axis=axis, equal_var=equal_var,
                           nan_policy=nan_policy)
    if alternative == 'greater':
        if tval < 0:
            pval = 1 - pval / 2
        else:
            pval = pval / 2
    elif alternative == 'less':
        if tval < 0:
            pval /= 2
        else:
            pval = 1 - pval / 2
    else:
        assert alternative == 'two.sided'
    return tval, pval
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you look at this:
[How to calculate the statistics "t-test" with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324438/how-to-calculate-the-statistics-t-test-with-numpy)

I think that is exactly what this questions is looking at.

Basically:

```
import scipy.stats
x = [1,2,3,4]
scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(x, 0)

Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=3.872983346207417, pvalue=0.030466291662170977)
```

is the same result as this example in R. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51242/statistical-difference-from-zero