# One Sided One Sample T Test Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In Python I'm using SciPy for a one sample t test:

```
from scipy import stats

one_sample_data = [177.3, 182.7, 169.6, 176.3, 180.3, 179.4, 178.5, 177.2, 181.8, 176.5]

one_sample = stats.ttest_1samp(one_sample_data, 175.3)
```

This is a two tailed test, but I can't see an option in `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp` to do a one tailed test.

In R if I was using `t.test()` I would simply set `alternative="less"` (or "greater"). What's the easiest way to do this in Python?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984221/how-to-perform-two-sample-one-tailed-t-test-with-numpy-scipy

Comment: @MishaVacic that answers the question - I thought about flagging duplicate but although the answer is the same, the question is actually a bit different. Do you want to write an answer with the information from the one you linked to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform two-sample one-tailed t-test with numpy/scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984221/how-to-perform-two-sample-one-tailed-t-test-with-numpy-scipy)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the link provided in the comments, I would do the following:

```
from scipy import stats
def one_sample_one_tailed(sample_data, popmean, alpha=0.05, alternative='greater'):
    t, p = stats.ttest_1samp(sample_data, popmean)
    print ('t:',t)
    print ('p:',p)
    if alternative == 'greater' and (p/2 < alpha) and t > 0:
        print ('Reject Null Hypothesis for greater-than test')
    if alternative == 'less' and (p/2 < alpha) and t < 0:
        print ('Reject Null Hypothesis for less-thane test')
sample_data = [177.3, 182.7, 169.6, 176.3, 180.3, 179.4, 178.5, 177.2, 181.8, 176.5]        
one_sample_one_tailed(sample_data,175.3)
```

this gives the output:

```
t: 2.295568968083183
p: 0.04734137339747034
Reject Null Hypothesis for greater-than test
```

This solution is based on the accepted answer in the link:

> It goes on to say that scipy always gives the test statistic as
>   signed. This means that given p and t values from a two-tailed test,
>   you would reject the null hypothesis of a greater-than test when p/2 <
>   alpha and t > 0, and of a less-than test when p/2 < alpha and t < 0.

Comment: How to get a p-value only?

Answer (score 1):

Now 'alternative' parameter available with the newest version of Scipy (>=1.6)
Here is the link :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html