# How to calculate p-value for two lists of floats?

Tags: python, statistics

So I have lists of floats. Like `[1.33,2.555,3.2134,4.123123]` etc. Those lists are mean frequencies of something. How do I proof that two lists are different? I thought about calculating p-value. Is there a function to do that? I looked through scipy documentation, but couldn't figure out what to use.

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: You mean like a [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)? Yes there is such a function in [`scipy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html)

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Ill try one of these.

Comment: I'm not sure if p-value is what you're looking for. Not just t-test, various others like [scipy.stats.spearmanr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html), [scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) also provides p-value. So, it is more like - when you perform a hypothesis test in statistics, a p-value helps you determine the significance of your results.

Comment: have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324438/how-to-calculate-the-statistics-t-test-with-numpy

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's say you have a list of floats like this:

```
>>> data = {
...     'a': [0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2],
...     'b': [0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1],
...     'c': [4.9, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2],
... }
```

Clearly, `a` is very similar to `b`, but both are different from `c`.

There are two kinds of comparisons you may want to do.

1. **Pairwise**: Is `a` similar to `b`? Is `a` similar to `c`? Is `b` similar to `c`?
2. **Combined**: Are `a`, `b` and `c` drawn from the same group? (This is generally a [better question](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/one-way-anova-statistical-guide-2.php))

The former can be achieved using independent [t-tests](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) as follows:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
>>> for list1, list2 in combinations(data.keys(), 2):
...     t, p = ttest_ind(data[list1], data[list2])
...     print list1, list2, p
...
a c 9.45895002589e-09
a b 0.315333596201
c b 8.15963804843e-09
```

This provides the relevant p-values, and implies that that `a` and `c` are
different, `b` and `c` are different, but `a` and `b` may be similar.

The latter can be achieved using the [one-way ANOVA](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html) as follows:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import f_oneway
>>> t, p =  f_oneway(*data.values())
>>> p
7.959305946160327e-12
```

The p-value indicates that `a`, `b`, and `c` are unlikely to be from the same population.

Comment: Thank you for your time to break it down to me. I did some reading and it seems that I have to use scipy.stats.chi2_contingency function, since I am comparing mean values from two independent populations. Is it correct?

Comment: No @YKY -- you'd use the chi2 test to test if the *frequency counts* of a dataset are dependent. If your array values are `float`s instead of `int`s, you definitely do not want `chi2_contingency`. You want `ttest_ind`

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Also, why chi2 will not work with floats?

Comment: @YKY chi2 is intended to compare expected *frequencies* with actual *frequencies*. Frequencies are always integers, not floats. It's just an easy test that we can use to check if we're applying the wrong kind of analysis. If we apply chi2 to floats, then we're applying the wrong technique, because a frequency cannot be a float