# pandas check if two values are statistically different

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I have a pandas dataframe which has some values for Male and some for Female. I would like to calculate if the percentage of both genders' values is **significantly different or not and tell confidence intervals of these rates**. Given below is the sample code:

```
data={}
data['gender']=['male','female','female','male','female','female','male','female','male']
data['values']=[10,2,13,4,11,8,14,19,2]
df_new=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_new.head()   # make a simple data frame


    gender  values
0   male    10
1   female  2
2   female  13
3   male    4
4   female  11

df_male=df_new.loc[df_new['gender']=='male']
df_female=df_new.loc[df_new['gender']=='female']   # separate male and female

# calculate percentages
male_percentage=sum(df_male['values'].values)*100/sum(df_new['values'].values)
female_percentage=sum(df_female['values'].values)*100/sum(df_new['values'].values)

# want to tell whether both percentages are statistically different or not and what are their confidence interval rates
print(male_percentage)
print(female_percentage)
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use t-test.In this case, use a two t test, meaning you are comparing values/means of two samples.

*I am applying an alternative hypothesis; A!=B. 
I do this by testing the null hypothesis A=B. This is achieved by calculating a p value. When p falls below a critical value, called alpha, I reject the null hypothesis. Standard value for alpha is 0.05. Below 5% probability, the sample will produce patterns similar to observed values*

Extract Samples, in this case a list of `values`

```
A=df[df['gender']=='male']['values'].values.tolist()
B=df[df['gender']=='female']['values'].values.tolist()
```

Using scipy library, do the t -test

```
from scipy import stats
t_check=stats.ttest_ind(A,B)
t_check
alpha=0.05
if(t_check[1]<alpha):
    print('A different from B')
```

Comment: It is just giving mean. Not telling whether means are statistically different.

Comment: What do to mean by statistically different. Easier to inferiantiate with added variables. Or did you want something like a t test？

Comment: something like a t-test I think.

Comment: This post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324438/how-to-calculate-the-statistics-t-test-with-numpy can help

Comment: @wwnde : The link that you provided just explained the t-test for list of sample and does not answer the questions if the percentages are different.  I think Asim was looking for "Testing Equality of Two Percentages" which is explained here : https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/percentageTests.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_new.groupby('gender')['values'].sum()/df_new['values'].sum()*100

gender
female    63.855422
male      36.144578
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It is just giving mean. Not telling whether means are statistically different.